# QTableView: change precision for double values

Tags: qt

If a double value returned as EditRole by a model, then (supposedly) QDoubleSpinBox is used by QTableView as an editor. How can I change precision in that control?

Answer (score 4):

The precision behavior of QDoubleSpinBox in a QTableView is explained [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/71692/using-setdata-qt-editrole-xxx-with-qtablewidgetitem/2) , so to solve the problem , you need to set your own QDoubleSpinBox, there are two ways to do this according to the end part of [Subclassing QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#subclassing-qstyleditemdelegate):
using an editor item factory or subclassing QStyledItemDelegate. The latter way requires you to reimplement four methods of QStyledItemDelegate, I just fount it a bit lengthy, so I choose the first way , sample code in PyQt following :

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class ItemEditorFactory(QItemEditorFactory):  # http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#subclassing-qstyleditemdelegate    It is possible for a custom delegate to provide editors without the use of an editor item factory. In this case, the following virtual functions must be reimplemented:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def createEditor(self, userType, parent):
        if userType == QVariant.Double:
            doubleSpinBox = QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
            doubleSpinBox.setDecimals(3)
            doubleSpinBox.setMaximum(1000)  # The default maximum value is 99.99.所以要设置一下
            return doubleSpinBox
        else:
            return super().createEditor(userType, parent)




styledItemDelegate=QStyledItemDelegate()
styledItemDelegate.setItemEditorFactory(ItemEditorFactory())
self.tableView.setItemDelegate(styledItemDelegate)
self.tableView.setModel(self.sqlTableModel)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to find a good way to get at those spin boxes. The default delegate for a `QTableView` is a [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html). When creating a item in `Qt::EditRole` it uses items created by the default [QItemEditorFactory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemeditorfactory.html) class, which you can access using `QItemEditorFactory::defaultFactory()`. You could then register your own editor there, however I do not see a good way to edit the ones that are already there.

Instead most likely what you should do is implement your own delegate with a different precision specified. There is a [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html) to make a delegate using a `QSpinBox`, which you would replace with a `QDoubleSpinBox`. Then in `createEditor` you would then use `setDecimals` to set the spin box to the precision that you want. You then apply that delegate to your table with `setItemDelegate`.

Comment: As for using an editor item factory to solve the problem (I think it a bit neat!), see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51763156/1485853

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdoublespinbox.html#decimals-prop), the precision of `QDoubleSpinBox` can be changed by calling `decimals`.

Comment: I think you need to explain how to access the double spin box editor to change the precision.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal `QStyledItemDelegate` implementation that modifies the `QDoubleSpinBox` precision:

```
const int DOUBLESP_PRECISION = 6;

class SpinBoxDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
        {
            auto w = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(
                parent, option, index);

            auto sp = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(w);
            if (sp)
            {
                sp->setDecimals(DOUBLESP_PRECISION);
            }
            return w;
        }
};
```

Comment: The subclassing QStyledItemDelegate way requires you to reimplement four methods of QStyledItemDelegate according to the end part of [Subclassing QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#subclassing-qstyleditemdelegate)

Comment: @iMath it is not necessary to implement all the methods.

Comment: @iMath above code is tested and works as expected. Other methods are already implemented by the `QStyledItemDelegate`. I just didn't have to change their behavior.